# Check if alertview is displayed

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

In my app I display tow alert views. The second alert view should pop up if the first has been closed. Now I check if an alert view is displayed like this:

```
    let appDelegate  = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let viewController = appDelegate.window!.rootViewController as! ViewController

    if viewController.view.window != nil {


    }

    else {

        let alertView = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("IAP", comment: "comment"), message: NSLocalizedString("IAP1", comment: "comment"), preferredStyle: .Alert)
        alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))
        viewController.presentViewController(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

I send the 2nd alert view if the first isn't displayed anymore. But if the first view is still displayed the 2nd alert view doesn't pops up anymore. So my question is if there's a waiting line for alert views and how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should define a handler for the first action and present the 2nd alertView within the handler.

So instead of

```
UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
```

you should do

```
UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Cancel) { (action) -> Void in
            // Present the other alertView
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I don't have an influence of the first alert view. So I can't add actions to the first view. Do you have another idea?

Comment: If you're not the one displaying the first popup, unfortunately, there is no way for you to be notified when it is closed. You can only check whether it is currently displayed  or not and that's not what you want

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a navigation controller, the general way to see if an alert is already displayed is to check the presentedViewController property.

```
if let _ = navigationController.presentedViewController {
     print("is already presenting \(navigationController.presentedViewController)")
} else {
     navigationController.presentViewController(alert, animated:true, completion:nil)
}
```

Comment: Ok, and how can I see if an alert view has ended displaying?

Answer (score 0):

For a fast patch in any UIViewController : (Xcode 8.3.1 & Swift 3.1)

```
func blabla() {
    if presentedViewController != nil {
         delay(0.5, closure: {
             self.blabla()
         })
         return
    }

    // other alert code here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simple way to check in Swift**

```
var isAlertViewPresenting: Bool {
     get {
        if self.presentedViewController is UIAlertController {
             return true
         }
        return false
        }
 }
```